# Xcode non relative project paths embedded into release binary

Tags: ios, xcode

I have stumbled upon fairly annoying issue with the Xcode iOS application, Xcode version is 10.1 but I recall this issue being existent for very long time.

Release version of our application does contain full paths to some of sources of the project, I thought that these are **FILE** macros from assertions, that was the case for only few of them. It is caused by some Swift libraries but there is nothing specific about them or in these files.

Paths were found in the release version of binary, however debug version contains much more of them which is reasonable, what isn't, is that they remain in the release. What We tried to resolve:

- manually eliminate them but couldn't find any more asserts/NSAsserts
- adding preprocessing flags NDEBUG and NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS neither of
  them made any change whatsoever.
- Trying to force Xcode to use relative paths, but We didn't have luck with that

For now, We are using some no so tidy solution with is moving project onto very root path and build release from there, which scrapes most of the path.

What is even more interesting if one takes a look at unencrypted binaries of major popular iOS applications, most of them contain such paths.

Comment: in Release build in Xcode 10.1 the only full paths I see are from `FILE` macros as you mention. What is the concern? For publicly released binaries we only expose the file paths of the build server which are basically random anyway. Meanwhile, these perfectly redundant data compresses well :)

Comment: I'm building with my private computer, perhaps I should change this practice. Anyway I just don't understand the reason why FILE macros are included with full path instead relative if needed at all! I didn't see any need for that in classes I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, only workaround I found is to move project to the main disc "/". Compile release from there, then it does not have full User paths.If anyone have better solution I'd love to hear it.